# 'command not found' when part of a bash function

Tags: bash

when logged in as the 'oas_mgr' user I can execute the following command which stops a specific service: serviceacontrol -S.

I want to try and create a function which will execute this at a given time. Unfortunately though I cannot get the 'serviceacontrol -S' to execute when part of a function.

This line: sudo -u oas_mgr sh -c 'cd /local/users/conf; serviceacontrol -S results in -bash: serviceacontrol: command not found

This line: sudo -u oas_mgr sh -c 'cd /local/users/conf; "serviceacontrol -S" results in -bash: serviceacontrol -S: command not found

Comment: as logged do `which serviceacontrol` and share the result with us,

Comment: @Ôrel not sure what you're asking me to do here... sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can compare 2 `PATH` (from `env`):

```
sudo -u oas_mgr sh -c 'echo $PATH'

# AND

echo $PATH
```

This "problem" should be missing path for locating command `serviceacontrol` in default shell (`sh`).

You can type:

```
which serviceacontrol
```

to check where is it.

And put the result into `sh -c`.

For example:

```
which serviceacontrol

# /opt/bin/serviceacontrol 

# then
sudo -u oas_mgr sh -c 'cd /local/users/conf; /opt/bin/serviceacontrol -S'
```

Note:

1. You may need to check the `.bashrc` (or other `.*rc` if you're using another shell.) to figure out where/how the `serviceacontrol` is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ktc. I have done as you suggested and got further but still it doesn't execute serviceacontrol. After entering 'which serviceacontrol' I was presented with /opt/dir/dir2/bin/serviceacontrol.

I amended the script to sudo -u oas_mgr sh -c 'cd /local/users/conf; /opt/dir/dir2/bin/serviceacontrol -S'

Once it runs I know get tee: /serviceacontrol.log: Permission denied
Only user _mgr can start/stop